# cheque (or check) printing with html php web app

Tags: javascript, php, json, xml, html

I am working on a solution that gives all the details for a check like the payment details and the name and address of the person to be paid.

I want to use web technologies like html, xml, php etc. to print the check details on a physical check as quick-books does.

I've tried it with adjusting the pixels and font size everything as per the ISO check standard, but I believe its not a good solution for the problem. Is there any API or anything available for this purpose with xml/json or any other type of data ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Anyway. Whenever I end up in a situation where I have to print data on paper and I need to be able to set the coördinates for this data, I prefer to generate a PDF file for it with a library like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)